# GitHub Action with `push: tags` not running with multiple tags

Tags: github-actions

I've got a workflow to release my project's CLI if the commit is tagged with `scyllax-cli-*`.

It works when the commit only has one tag. However, when there are multiple, the workflow doesn't trigger.

```yaml
name: (CLI) Release

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'scyllax-cli-*'

jobs:
  publish_cli:
```

I forget this happens, and I have to delete and re-create the tag on an empty commit, but I shouldn't have to do that.

Am I misunderstanding [`on.push.tags`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushbranchestagsbranches-ignoretags-ignore)? Does it expect *every* tag on the commit to match `scyllax-cli-*`? If so, what's the alternative?

Workflow: https://github.com/trufflehq/scyllax/blob/main/.github/workflows/release-cli.yml
Commit: https://github.com/trufflehq/scyllax/commit/2446877116a7aa8bfc4890ecdfb76c1db5fb85ae

Comment: Did you try without using quote? `- scyllax-cli-*`